# c++ pow function- invalid result?

Tags: c++, function, math, pow

Why is the output of the dResult invalid ?
Env: Visual Studio 2008

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])  
{  
   double dN = - 0.091023604111478473 ;  
   double dD = 0.127777777777777;  
   double dResult =  pow( dN,dD );   
   //dResult = -1.#IND000000000000  
   return 0;  
}
```

Comment: Did you remember to `#include <cmath>` or `<math.h>`?

Comment: Don't use `_tmain` and `_TCHAR` or `_T` anything unless you don't know if your app is going to need to support Unicode. Seems to me that any code is either: 1) destined to be used "in the real world", and needs to support unicode (use `wmain` and `WCHAR`), or 2) short-lived throwaway code with only you as its audience in which case you don't need to pretend. `_T*` is a waste of effort. Besides, for moderately complex code if you don't compile it both ways, it's not going to compile the way you don't usually test.

Comment: #include "stdafx.h"   #include <stdio.h> #include <math.h> int main() { double dN = -0.09 ; double dD = 0.127 ; double dResult = pow(dN,dD) ; return 0; }

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cmath/pow/

```
double pow (double base, double exponent );
```

"If base is negative and exponent is not an integral value, or if base is zero and exponent is negative, a domain error occurs, setting the global variable errno to the value EDOM."

Answer (score 3):

If your dD value was .25 instead of the fraction you've presented then you could see that it is really taking the fourth root instead of an exponential of a negative number.  Your fraction is close to the eighth root.  You need complex numbers to express the answer that function should give.

Answer (score 3):

That's the expected result because dN is negative. The result of pow( dN,dD ); is only defined if either dN is positive or if dD is an integer. Otherwise, the result is a complex number. For example, pow(-1., 0.5) won't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Well, 0.127777777 is what number? its smt like 1277777777/(10....0)

1277777777777 is not an even number, therefore -smt to the power of 12777777777 is a negative number, and 10...0th root from that is not a real number.

I'm reffering to a fact that a^(b/c) = (c-th root from)(a^b)