# C++ POW(X,Y) X negative double and Y negative double, gives nan as result

Tags: c++, pow

I'm trying to do a simple operation, `pow(-0.89,-0.67)` in my C++ 14 code, and it gives a `NaN` as result. When doing the same in SciLab the result is -1.08. Is there any way in C++ to get the right result?

Comment: [Read the documentation for the functions you use](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow).

Comment: The "right" result will be a complex number, see [Wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=+pow%28-0.89%2C-0.67%29+).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am guessing that you made a typo in SciLab. You must have written

```
-0.89 ^ -0.67
```

Which means you did -(0.89 ^ -0.67) = -(1.08).

If you instead typed

```
(-0.89) ^ -0.67
```

You would have gotten the answer  -0.5504 - 0.9306i. The negative root of a negative number is complex, and the `pow` function in C++ will give you a NaN result.

If you use the `std::complex` type, you will get the correct answer of -0.5504 - 0.9306i:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <complex>
#include <cmath>

int main()
{
    std::complex<double> a(-0.89), b(-0.67);
    std::cout << std::pow(a,b) << std::endl; 
}
```

output:

```
(-0.550379,-0.93064)
```

Comment: I thought of complex, but didn't choose to go for it, thanks for doing so, +1. Do you think that I should delete my answer, because yours is good and mine's has a -1? Never mind, it got retracted.

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation of [pow()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/pow/), you have:

> If base is negative and exponent is not an integral value, or if base is zero and exponent is negative, a domain error occurs, setting the global variable errno to the value EDOM.

So, the nan result you are getting is expected.

---

You could do it like this:

```
printf ("-0.89 ^ -0.67 = %f\n", -pow (0.89,-0.67) );
```

which gives:

`-0.89 ^ -0.67 = -1.081207`

---

Links I was based into:

1. [c++ pow function- invalid result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4108411/c-pow-function-invalid-result)
2. [pow() problem](http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/220536-pow-problem)

---

<sub>Nice question, +1!</sub>

Comment: Just as a side note http://www.cplusplus.com/ is not officially affiliated with the C/C++ standard and therefore it may not be the best place to look at (even though the material is IMO 99% right)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. But it is much more user-friendly (maybe because it's more elegant IMHO). I would really like to know that 1%!

Answer (score 0):

It's always good to consult the standard:
http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf
It says:

> — pow(x, y) returns a NaN and raises the ‘‘invalid’’ floating-point
>   exception for finite x < 0 and finite non-integer y.

Therefore, your C++ compiler is right. It should return NaN.